# RH2: Using R cannot connect to my H2 database

Tags: r, h2

I read the documentation of RH2 on CRAN but when I'm trying to connect to my H2 database I get this error:

```
> library(RH2)
Loading required package: chron
Loading required package: RJDBC
Loading required package: DBI
Loading required package: rJava
> con <- dbConnect(H2(), "jdbc:h2:mem:test")
Error in .local(drv, ...) : could not find function ".verify.JDBC.result"
```

WHere I'm wrong?

Comment: TRy to follow the example in ?H2 . Your second arguments looks wrong.

Comment: I tried this and there is the same error: con <- dbConnect(H2(), "jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", "") Error in .local(drv, ...) : could not find function ".verify.JDBC.result"

Comment: I get the same error.  It seems that RJDBC has been updated in such a way as to break RH2.  Use RJDBC 2.0 until its fixed.

Comment: RH2 version 0.1-2.9 is now on CRAN and fixes this problem.

Comment: with RH2 0.1-2.9 and RJDBC 0.2-1 the problem remains

Comment: I am able to reproduce this so go back to RJDBC 2.0 again until its fixed.

Comment: I have updated the package again.  If you want a copy to test it send me an email.  (See http://cran.r-project.org/package=RH2 for my address.)