# How to implement an In-Memory database accessible from multiple R sessions inside a JVM?

Tags: r, jvm, h2, in-memory-database, rjdbc

I'm writing a program that spawns multiple R sessions inside a single JVM. I need to share data between these sessions and I'm writing files (RData/txt) on to the disk for now. I did a bit of reading and found out that an in-memory database is the right way to go, and zeroed in on H2.
I downloaded & installed the RH2 package and the documentation said that it includes an H2 instance- I don't need to separately install one.

So I went ahead and tried to create my db:

```
con <- dbConnect(H2(), "jdbc:h2:mem:test", "sa", " ")
```

And got an error:

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) : could not find function ".verify.JDBC.result"
```

I read this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907092/rh2-using-r-cannot-connect-to-my-h2-database), and tried:

```
> con <- dbConnect(H2(), "jdbc:h2:mem:test")
Error in .local(drv, ...) : could not find function ".verify.JDBC.result"
> con <- dbConnect(H2(), "jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1")
Error in .local(drv, ...) : could not find function ".verify.JDBC.result"
> con <- dbConnect(H2(), "jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", "")
Error in .local(drv, ...) : could not find function ".verify.JDBC.result"
```

I went through the documentation, but it was not of a lot of help. I checked for my drivers, and it gave:

```
> H2()
An object of class "H2Driver"
Slot "identifier.quote":
[1] "\""

Slot "jdrv":
[1] "Java-Object{org.h2.Driver@25e01f19}"
```

How do I go ahead and create a database from within R? Also, is it possible to share this database across different sessions?

Update: I switched to older instances of both RJDBC and RH2, but same result.

Comment: How about use the in-memory database `redis`(http://redis.io/) with R interface `rredis`(http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rredis/index.html)?

Comment: I'll try it out and get back. However I feel this is also an important problem to solve.